# Render video from Raw image in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I have a Unity project for Android, which has a raw image, in which many elements are displayed that respond to a track that is played in a central audio source. And I want to export the video of the raw image for the time it reacts when the track of the audio source is playing.
But unfortunately, Unity does not support video recording while playing.
I know that it is possible for Unity to render video from the scene, because there is a program called SeeMusic, built in Unity, and it does a similar process with visualization to a MIDI file, and it knows how to render video from it.
So my question is, what is the method of exporting the video?

I tried to use cinemachine, but in the end you have to use unity recorder, and it only supports the editor.
I also understood that you can extract all the frames into a folder, then use FFMpeg to put them into one video file, but I couldn't figure out how to use ffmpeg for a Unity Android project.